# Large query as variable not evaluating in dataflow expression builder SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am querying a Cache database through an ADO net datasource in my dataflow in SSIS (SQL 2008 R2). I want to pass parameters to the query but can only do this through the expressions section of the dataflow item. The query itself is over 4000 characters hence I cant use the query in the expressions section (due to the 4000 character limitation) in its raw form.

I have tried using a script task to assign the query to a string variable [User::Query1] however when I click the Evaluate Expression button in the expression builder screen of the dataflow, it returns nothing. I have the following expression for [ADO NET Source].[SQLCommand]:

```
@[User::Query1]
```

When running the package, I get a an error saying that SQL command has not been set correctly. Check SQLCommand Property.

I've set ValidateExternalMetaData to false and I see the following error in the execution results;

```
Error: The variable User::Query1 contains a string that exceeds the maximum allowed length of 4000 characters.
Error: Reading the variable "User::Query1" failed with error code 0xC0047100.
Error: The expression "@[User::Query1]" on property "[ADO NET Source].[SqlCommand]" cannot be evaluated. Modify the expression to be valid.
```

In my script task I have the entire query assigned to a string variable and then I am assigning the string to the actual variable using the vb code below:

```
Dts.Variables("User::Query1").Value = sSql
MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables("User::Query1").Value.ToString())
```

On the script task properties, I have [User::Query1] as a ReadWriteVariables. I have also made sure that EvaluateAsExpression for [User::Query1] is set to true.

In essence, I am trying to run the query using the expressions property of the dataflow as this will allow me to use dynamic parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

Also variables are limited to 4000 chars in SSIS, you could split the query in multiple sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution when you use an OLE DB connection. It is complex to prepare but finally it is running OK. Previously, you need to define the variable with a similar and same structure query and <4000 characters to validate the expression. When is all ok, you can redefine the variable with >4000 characters  query in a script task. 
Next link explain how to do it.
[ssis more than 4000 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241888/ssis-more-than-4000-chars)

Answer (score 0):

After version SQL 2012 (I think) the limitation of the variable size does not exist.

However for example in SQL 2017 you can put a large amount of data in a string variable (I tried with more than 20 MB) and it works fine. But when you try to do string operations on it, in an expression like FINDSTRING or such then you get DTS_E_EXPREVALSTRINGVARIABLETOOLONG error.

My solution to sort this out was to use a script task, because in .NET you do not have this limitation.